# Why doesn't family of finite nonempty sets have choice function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

If F is a (potentially infinite) family of finite nonempty sets, why doesn't it have a choice function even in ZF? By definition, finite sets have a bijection with an initial set of natural numbers, so can't you use the bijection for each set in F to select the element that maps to 1? And for that matter, if F is a family of countable sets then each C in F has an injection to the naturals, which are well-ordered. So can't you use the injection to map each C in F to its member that maps to the minimal element of the range of the injection from C to the naturals?

Comment: Tsvi, my friend, you are just pushing the problem up a level! A finite set has many such bijections, before you find which element maps to $1$ you have to choose such a bijection.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean

Comment: One can introduce a well-ordering on the union of the family of sets, and use that to construct injections ... but well-ordering is stronger than the axiom of choice, so—!

Comment: @GregMartin "well-ordering is stronger than the axiom of choice" In what sense? Over $\mathsf{ZF}$, they're equivalent.

Comment: I believe well-ordering is strictly stronger than the axiom of choice in second-order logic. That being said, the OP is explicitly working in ZF, so maybe that's a bit too far afield.